# Why await/async in Javascript does not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, async-await

As a way to learn async/await in Javascript, I created the following JSFiddle sample code

```
async function func1() {
  return await setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('execute func1');
  }, 5000);
}

async function func2() {
  return await setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('execute func2');
  }, 2000);
}

async function mainFunc() {
    await func1();
  await func2();

  console.log('execute completed'); 
}

mainFunc();
```

Since I have await, I expected the output will be:

```
execute func1
execute func2
execute complete
```

But to my surprise, the output is

```
execute complete
execute func2
execute func1
```

I must have missed some important concept on this, any suggestion is highly welcomed.

Comment: You can only `await` promises. `setTimeout` does __not__ return a promise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### You have to create a promise inside func1 and func2

This is easy to do once you get the hang of it, but not at all obvious if you haven't practiced.

`setTimeout` itself does not return a promise: it returns a reference to the timer that can be used to cancel the timeout process.

To get a Promise instead, use the `new Promise` constructor. In simple use, you feed in the word `resolve`, and the function you want to run, in this case `setTimeout`. At the point in your function that you want to return a result, do not use `return`: instead use `resolve`.

For example, if you wanted to return the number `42` after a 1 second delay, you can use the following. It in fact *immediately* returns a promise that, after 1 second, resolves to the number `42`. To get the effect of returning a value after a delay, you would need to `await` the result.

```
return new Promise(resolve, setTimeout(()=>{resolve(42)},1000)
```

In your case you don't want to return any particular result from the setTimeout, so you don't need to put anything inside the parentheses of `resolve`.

The word `resolve` is in fact a dummy function name: you could use any variable name but it is conventional to call it `resolve` to prevent unnecessary bafflement for readers.

```js
async function func1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
    () => {
      console.log('execute func1');
      resolve()
    }, 5000))
}

async function func2() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
    () => {
      console.log('execute func2');
      resolve()
    }, 2000))
}

async function mainFunc() {
  await func1();
  await func2();
  console.log('execute completed');
}

mainFunc();
```